# Wrote an Azure app using golang-sdk, trying to access resources from within a Linux VM, but cannot get response back

Tags: azure, go

New to Azure go sdk, just trying to develop a tool running inside a linux VM to manage public IPs, got my first piece of code to list subnets in a VNet to test on, the app is running fine within another Ubuntu VM in the same group. but can not get any response in this VM. From tcpdump, server actually responded but the app actively closed the connection.
Any idea what might be the cause? or how should I further debug it? Thanks!

The app will get authorizer from managed identity since it's running inside a VM

```
bash# ./tcpdump -n "host 169.254.269.254 or host 40.78.254.1"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on port1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:22:11.001255 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [S], seq 2293578849, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
12:22:11.001948 IP 40.78.254.1.443 > 10.0.0.4.51378: Flags [S.], seq 1134926654, ack 2293578850, win 65535, options [mss 1440,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:22:11.001968 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 29, length 0
12:22:11.002387 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:269, ack 1, win 29, length 268
12:22:11.005157 IP 40.78.254.1.443 > 10.0.0.4.51378: Flags [P.], seq 1:6046, ack 269, win 16425, length 6045
12:22:11.005188 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [.], ack 6046, win 41, length 0
12:22:11.006557 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [P.], seq 269:276, ack 6046, win 41, length 7
12:22:11.006594 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [F.], seq 276, ack 6046, win 41, length 0
12:22:11.007076 IP 40.78.254.1.443 > 10.0.0.4.51378: Flags [.], ack 277, win 16424, length 0
12:22:11.007470 IP 40.78.254.1.443 > 10.0.0.4.51378: Flags [R.], seq 6046, ack 277, win 0, length 0
```

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "encoding/json"

        "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/compute/mgmt/2020-06-01/compute"
        "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/network/mgmt/2020-05-01/network"

        "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest"
        "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"

        "net/http"
        "net/http/httputil"
)

// AzureSession is an object representing session for subscription
type AzureSession struct {
        SubscriptionID string
        Authorizer     autorest.Authorizer
}

func newSession() (*AzureSession, error) {
        authorizer, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error: %s\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Got authorizer! %v\n", authorizer)
        sess := AzureSession{
                SubscriptionID: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                Authorizer:     authorizer,
        }

        return &sess, nil
}

func getSubnets(sess *AzureSession, rg, vnet string) {
        subnClient := network.NewSubnetsClient(sess.SubscriptionID)
        subnClient.Authorizer = sess.Authorizer

        fmt.Printf("subnClient: %T\n", subnClient)
        res, err := subnClient.List(context.Background(), rg, vnet)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        }
        num := len(res.Values())
        for i:=0; i<num; i++ {
                fmt.Printf("%T\n", res.Values()[i])
                jstr, err := json.MarshalIndent(&res.Values()[i], "", "  ")
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                }
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(jstr))
        }
}

func main() {
        sess, err := newSession()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        getSubnets(sess, "test-rg", "test-vnet")
}
```

Comment: If the same app runs fine on a different VM, then this isn't a programming issue, it's a server issue; you might get more help on ServerFault where the sysadmins hang out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
12:22:11.002387 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:269, ack 1, win 29, length 268
```

You are likely using HTTPS here (port 443) so this first packet is the TLS ClientHello.

```
12:22:11.005157 IP 40.78.254.1.443 > 10.0.0.4.51378: Flags [P.], seq 1:6046, ack 269, win 16425, length 6045
```

This long response is the response from the server which contains the certificate.

```
12:22:11.006557 IP 10.0.0.4.51378 > 40.78.254.1.443: Flags [P.], seq 269:276, ack 6046, win 41, length 7
```

This is a very short message from the client, very likely a TLS alert. While it is unknown what is inside the alert it likely is that the client does not like the servers certificate. Given that you did not provide any useful details about your app you need to  look yourself at the app for more details about the problem and how it can be solved.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your answer, I added code in the post. Just wondering if it's cert issue, will there be any error message from the SDK that can be printed out?

Comment: @AlanKang: I don't know the API of this SDK. But I'm pretty sure that there is error handling in various places possible. But you don't even show where in your code it fails and with which error although you capture and print errors.